# Asp.net runat="server" changes id

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have the following html, which I need to `runat="server"`

```
<h2 class="admin-manager-table-header" runat="server" id="hdrBorrower">Borrower</h2>
```

I then have the following CSS:

```
.admin-manager-table-header#headerPending, .admin-manager-table-header#hdrBorrower {
    background-color: rgb(0, 176, 240);
}
```

Which no longer works as the server has changed the id to:

```
ctl00_body_hdrBorrower
```

So my CSS is now

```
.admin-manager-table-header#headerPending, .admin-manager-table-header#hdrBorrower , .admin-manager-table-header#ctl00_body_hdrBorrower{
    background-color: rgb(0, 176, 240);
}
```

My question is two fold:

1.Will the server always change the id to this, or will it sometimes vary the ID?

2.If it is consistent in its naming of the ID, is it bad practice of me to use this ID in a CSS style sheet?

Comment: The generated ID is generated based on the IDs of the containers.  If your containers remain consistent, that ID will remain consistent, but I'd probably target a class to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, it's subject to change based on the location of the node within the DOM (as seen by the server before responding to the client). There are two slightly different algorithms .NET can use for generating the ID. See [Control.ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.100).aspx).

As of .NET 4.0, I believe you can make your hand-picked ID "stick" using a `ClientIdMode` attribute of *Static*.